# Requiring sikuli gem throwing an error

Tags: rubygems, sikuli

I installed sikuli gem by: gem install sikuli

But when I tried following:

```
require 'sikuli'
```

it threw following error:

```
LoadError: cannot load such file -- C:\Program Files (x86)\Sikuli X\/sikuli-script.jar
    from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sikuli-0.3.0/lib/sikuli.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
    from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
    from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
    from (irb):1
    from c:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

I've sikuli installed on my machine. Please help to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge n if we want to use gem 'sikuli'

1. You need java setup on your machine
2. 'Sikuli' works with jruby , so install jruby and go to jruby's IRB, and hit **"require 'Sikuli' "**

You can check details here

1. [Link-1](http://rubydoc.info/gems/sikuli/0.3.0/frames)
2. [Link-2](http://blackrat.org/ruby/getting-sikuli-script-working-with-jruby-on-the-mac/)